# Accessing external parameters and document in mongodb group aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

In a collection with the following general structure:

```
{_id: 'id1', clientId: 'cid1', clientName:'Jon', item: 'item1', dateOfPurchase: '...'},
{_id: 'id2', clientId: 'cid1', clientName:'Jon', item: 'item2', dateOfPurchase: '...'},
{_id: 'id3', clientId: 'cid2', clientName:'Doe', item: 'itemX', dateOfPurchase: '...'}
... etc
```

The objective is to create a grouping by `clientId` to calculate some simple statistics, e.g. total occurrences per clientId.

One way to achieve this using Node.js MongoDB Driver API [Collection.group method](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#group) is:

```
db.collection.group(
    'clientId',
    {},
    { count: 0 },
    function(obj, prev) {
        prev.count++;
    },
    true
}
```

The output of this for the sample data above would be similar to:

```
{clientId: 'cid1', count: 2}
{clientId: 'cid2', count: 1}
```

**Question 1:** what is the best way to pass some external values to the `reducer` function? For example I may want to calculate different counts for purchases made before/after a specific date and want to pass this date as a parameter. I know that with `mapReduce` I can use the `scope` option for this purpose. I'm wondering if there's a way to do this with the `group` function. I could use the iterator object but it feels hacky.

**Question 2:** is there a way to access the original document from inside the `finalize` function in order to include some extra data in the results? i.e. project extra fields from the original documents such as `clientName`:

```
{clientId: 'cid1', count: 2, clientName: 'Jon'}
{clientId: 'cid2', count: 1, clientName: 'Doe'}
```

Clarifications for Question 2, 
a) I could add the extra field inside the `reducer` function but it feels redundant to include code which is not supposed to run on every iteration. 
b) I could use aggregate pipelines to achieve something like this but I'm wondering if I can do this with `Collection.group` here

Answer (score 0):

While digging around the documentation I found an answer to **Question 1** which is to use the [Code class](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Code.html) for the reducer function. The `Code` constructor takes a second argument functioning exactly like `scope` in `mapReduce` e.g.:

```
const myFunction = function(obj, prev) {
    if (prev.count < myLimit) // myLimit is available here because it is defined in the Code initialization below
        prev.count++;
}

Code = require('mongodb').Code;
db.collection.group(
    'clientId',
    {},
    { count: 0 },
    new Code(myFunction, { myLimit: 5 }),
    true
}
```